# ElasticSearch querying across more than one index C#

Tags: elasticsearch

Is it possible to query across more than one index in one .Search query? 
Example of what I have in C#:

```
        ConnectionSettings connectionSettings = new ConnectionSettings(new Uri("http://localhost:9200/")); //local PC             
        ElasticClient elasticClient = new ElasticClient(connectionSettings);

        string index1 = "local-neal-test-other1-2018.04.06";
        string index2 = "local-neal-test-other2-2018.04.06";

        //Search query to retrieve info 
        var response = elasticClient.Search<Document2>(s => s
            .Index(index1)
            .Query (q=>q.
                   MatchAll()
                   )
            .Sort(ss => ss 
                 .Descending(p => p.CreatedDate))
             );
```

Example, can I put both index1 and index2 in the above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can explicitly tell ELK to use multiple indices:

```cs
elasticClient.Search<Document2>(s=>s
    .Index(new [] {"Index_A", "Index_B"})
    ...
)
```

Comment: Perfect, but it's actually .Index not .Indices.   I didn't notice until after I tested.  Then I tried .Indices and got compile error.  There is an indicesboost though.

Comment: Now, can you use any mask?